# How to save the uploaded file in server(my website) using java

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc

I am new to java,i want to upload the file(all types) and save it in database as well as server folder(www.example.com/images). How to store it server and how can i use the url direct in code.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a jQuery plugin that will get the base 64 datauri of a file from a file input. [Link is here](https://github.com/Pamblam/fileUpload). Sample usage:

```
$("#mybtn").fileUpload({
    change: function() {
        $("#mybtn").fileUpload("getDataURI", function(dataURI){
            // do stuff to upload it..
            console.log(dataURI);
        }); 
    }
});
```

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/no5umjnx/)

in this example, `#mybtn` doesn't have to be a file input, it can just be a button or anything.

That said, since base64 encoding your image will make it larger, it makes much more sense to upload the file to the server and then base64 encode it with php on the back-end.